# Jenkins schedule multiple versions of the same build

Tags: jenkins, triggers

I have a project that has 3-5 different mercurial branches going at all times. I want to schedule a weekly Jenkins test to run our tests on all relevant branches.

What I want, I think, is a parameterized build, with the branch name as the parameter, and then to have a list of branches, and once a week, run the parameterized build with each of the parameters in the list.

However, I see that you can't send parameters into a triggered build. I assume that there is a plugin for this. Is job Generator the correct plugin? Is there something better?

I should mention that currently, we are doing this with multiple SCMs, and having the body of the build have a sh loop that runs through each directory and runs the tests. This is really inefficient, and a pain to maintain...

Comment: `3-5 different mercurial branches` - do you need build only specific branches or all available (I mean, do you know names of branches which you would like build)?

Comment: Only certain ones. It will change periodically, but I will know the names of the branches.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest one solution but it couldn't be called elegant.

1. Firstly, you need create `multi-configuration` project (aka `Matrix` project).
   [image]
2. In this project you need declare one `node` (it can be already existed `master` node)
   [image]
   And one type of `axis` (for example `BRANCH` - be careful don't use [Jenkins Set Environment Variables variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project)) with values corresponding for each branch (for example `default`, `testing`, `devel`, etc).
   [image]
3. After you need add in your project `build` action in which you need check `environment` variable (previously declared $`BRANCH`) and discover for which branch this build was launched (the main idea is illustrated by example with using `bash`).
   [image]
4. And finally you need manually get sources from corresponding branch.
5. Next build steps can be the same for all branches.
   [image]

**This approach have set of drawbacks:**
1. You can not triggered this project by changes in repository (you can check using `Mercurial plugin` only one branch).
2. All subprojects will be rebuilt even if they have not changed.
3. Appropriate only for statically defined branches.
4. Not elegant.

**But it has one advantage versus** `parameterized` **build:**
1. All artifacts (and build logs) of branches is stored in separated directories (because they are separate subprojects).

Comment: Can I trigger this project by schedule? So it always gets run Saturday night, for example?

Comment: @BrianPostow, yes, without any difficulties.